# How does one return results from the google search appliance based on entity names?

Tags: google-search-appliance

My app needs to GET results from the GSA based on `entity name`, is this possible? I can retrieve results based on `metadata` using `requiredfields` but I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to retrieve results based on entity names (entity name:entity value pairs). Using the indexing diagnostics on the the GSA I can see that the GSA is tagging the appropriate docs with the correct entity name: entity value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entities are pushed as metadata, but their are prefixed with "gsaentity_", so it's really working the same way as metadata. The prefix is just there to avoid colliding with your existing metadata.

For instance, let's pick the default "Date" entity preloaded in the box. If you wanted to use it, you should do :

&requiredfields=gsaentity_Date:value

Comment: That was very helpful. I had not made the connection despite having used dynamic navigation.